# Wrong Date value if day or month properties are one digit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting wrong date when the value of either day or month properties are less than 2 digits(less than 10) since I have applied Date formatting in Global Asax file as "dd-mm-yyyy" .But i found day,month and year properties are correct for the date object .

Am i missing anything here ?

Thanks in advance
Subin

Comment: Can you give us some examples?

Comment: If the Date is Septmber 20 .Date vlue is 20/00/2019 .But when i inspect day -property it is 20 ,month-9 and year-2019 .

Comment: Please show us the code involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

instead of `"dd-mm-yyyy"`

Lower case `mm` means minutes. Upper case for months.